# Can someone tell me what kind of fitting for this toilet water shut off valve is?

Tags: plumbing, bathroom, toilet, old-house, shutoff

I've never seen anything like it. It's for my mom's house built in 1957. I want to know how to replace it in case we run into a leak or need to replace the toilet without shutting the water off at the main. I don't see any compression fitting so I'm assuming it's soldered on but it looks like the whole pipe is connected somehow (maybe into the wall) I'm new to this site so thank you for the help.[image]

[image]

Answer (score 5):

Looks like it flares out at the wall escutcheon.  Hard to be 100% but I'd bet it is 1/2" female NPT and connected to galvanized iron pipe water supply.

Probably something like [this](https://www.amazon.ca/Midline-Valve-82112QS-OM-Straight-Dishwasher/dp/B00MA9GA8K)

[image]

You could also just piggy back with a [3/8 x 3/8 stop valve](https://www.amazon.ca/BROTHERS-GIDDS-283396-Dahl-Retro-Fit-Female/dp/B00FL764V6).

[image: 3/8 x 3/8 stop valve]

Comment: Yes, we do have galvanized pipelines.

Comment: I see so what would be the best way to remove it? Any tips?

Comment: I'd start by removing the layers of paint and escutcheon... you can use tin snips to cut the escutcheon off the wall.   once you expose the valve then you can just use an adjustable wrench but you'll need to have the water off and you'll need tpfe tape when installing a new one.

Comment: the other option is to install a 3/8 compression x 3/8 compression stop and just have that in front of this one that likely doesn't work very well if at all currently.  you'd have 2 valves but other than being a little ugly it is the easiest solution.

Comment: Thank you for your reply! My biggest worry is getting a grip on the pipe inside the wall so I don't break it. I'm told this cast iron is tough to get off. Do you have any examples of the 3/8 x 3/8 compression stop? I'm curious how that would work if the valve started leaking.

Comment: it won't stop the first valve from leaking but if the first valve can't stop the water then this can help.  generally the valve don't leak unless you go to use them...   even if they do leak a little bit that can seal up with impurities especially if you have galv supply pipes as you'll have lots of impurities!

Comment: For an example of the compression stop, @DanielM, take this description to your local big-box store and ask an employee in the plumbing section. She'll take you to the valves and help you find one. They're pretty common. A 1/4-turn ball valve is likely to be more reliable and less likely to fail over time than a multi-turn gate valve, but other than that, whatever you find will work.

Comment: Thank you very much everyone!

Comment: Start thinking about a repipe for the house… 60 year old galvanized supply pipes are past due. (And personally, I’d go to great lengths to not turn that old valve…)

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I would love to repipe the house but unfortunately, that's out of the budget right now. House causes us so many problems with the plumbing. Just looking at little things that might go wrong and how to fix them fast in case they may do. Thank you!

Comment: Given all that, I’d prioritize having a main shutoff valve that works well.